# $.ajax "Get" based on page URL not working properly

Tags: xml, ajax, dynamic, onload

I'm trying to load a file based on the URL of the page being loaded with a var without success.

In this instance it is "http://www.cstv.com/gallerylink/00/12/02/120214.xml".

It works fine if I use the above URL but it needs to be dynamic. I've created a var (fileAddress) that recreates the URL and it checks out fine in the console but doesn't work in practice.

The site I'm attempting this with is http://www.cstv.com/view.gal?id=120214&template=player_noflash2

And the specific ajax request has the comment CAROUSEL CODE above it.

Any input one might have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Adding the if statement:

```
if (var != null)
```

To make sure that the ajax request was able to grab the needed data before firing.

Super simple.